# Conditional Resource Pools in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I’m trying to make a Seize block to choose from different resource pools depending on the agent type that is passing through the block.

My first try was to create a dynamic reference of the Resource set parameter in a Seize block as the image shows:

[image of dynamic value in Resource set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYEuv.png)

```
if(agent instanceof Pala || agent instanceof Torre){
    Extensibles;
}else{
    Camabajas3e;
}
```

where **Extensibles** and **Camabajas3e** are the resource pool names.

But I get the error:  “Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResourcePool to ResourcePool[][].”

My second attempt was to include both resource pools in the list and instead use the parameter “Resource choice condition” with the following code:

```
agent.vehículo==unit.vehículo
```

were **vehículo** es a parameter inside each agent type in the flowchart and each resource type from the resource pool.

But I get the error: “vehículo connot be resolved or is not a field” but it is a parameter inside agents and resources.

What I’m doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use units of the same pool instead of (alternative) resource sents

and in the code write this:

```
(agent instanceof Pala || agent instanceof Torre) ? Extensibles : Camabajas3e
```

with your second option you can actually use what you did, but you need to tell anylogic what is your agent type..

```
agent.vehiculo==((ResourceType)unit).vehiculo
```